# Div Slide on Click with links

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

If I have a div that slides on click like the one found in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/EVyE8/1229/

```
<div id="slide">click me
<br><a href="#">here is some more text</a>
<br><a href="#">here is some more text</a>
<br><a href="#">here is some more text</a>
<br><a href="#">here is some more text</a>
<br><a href="#">here is some more text</a></div>


JS:
document.getElementById('slide').addEventListener('click', function() {

(this.style.height == '50px' || this.style.height == '') ? this.style.height     
= '150px': this.style.height = '50px';

}, false);
```

What do I need to be considering if, once I click on the div and it slides to expand, I want to have links in the hidden part of the div.  If those links are clicked, I want the div to remain open until an open part of the div itself is clicked.

I am new to js and am avoiding jquery because I'd like to increase my proficiency in JS, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Click me does not have an anchor or element, give it an anchor and put the eventListener on the anchor. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EVyE8/1231/

```
<div id="slide"><a href="#" id="slide_click">click me</a><br><a href="#">here is some more text</a></div>

document.getElementById( 'slide_click' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
( this.parentElement.style.height == '50px' || this.parentElement.style.height == '' )
    ? this.parentElement.style.height = '150px' 
    : this.parentElement.style.height = '50px';
```

}, false );

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!

Comment: And this can only be done if the div itself is NOT the parent element correct?

Comment: Correct, because if you add an event listener to the parent, every click within the parent will trigger the slide open/close. if you want to be able to click on the background as well, you could use an extra background div with a click.

Comment: That makes sense.  Just building off that, since I've set an element as the parent that is controlling one action, if I also have an icon I want to animate on click, can I use the original parent item to control both the slide and the animation?  or do I need separate parent elements for each one?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your complete question on this one, but if at the same time you want to animate an icon, you can use the same click listener. but you could also give the icon a class and change the class on click.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a but jumbled.  Basically what I want is when the parent item is clicked, the div activates, which we have working.  But on that same click, I want an icon I have made with two lines (a simple plus to minus icon) to activate as well.  Since we made a <p> the parent element that has the event listener on it, would I have to declare the variable class for the animated icon within the function or do I need a separate one.  Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/theodore_steiner/cp7kq08m/

Comment: I don't think it is an ideal setup, but i changed your example in a basic way that should help you on your way learning javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/cp7kq08m/4/ *Edit: other jsfiddle link

Comment: That's very elegant.  So the if statement controls both of the actions but leaves the event listener free and attached to only one item

Comment: Correct! As mentioned, this code could be made cleaner but covers the basics! Good luck! (Don't want this to turn into slow chat)

Comment: Please mark an answer as the correct answer, Either mine or Adam are correct and it helps future users. (plus we get some bacon)

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the block the click event from the `div` by detecting clicks on it's child `a` tags.  Something like this would work:

```
var locked = false;

document.getElementById( 'slide' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {

    if(!locked) {
        ( this.style.height == '50px' || this.style.height == '' )
            ? this.style.height = '150px' 
            : this.style.height = '50px';
    }
    locked = false;
}, false );


var anchors = document.querySelectorAll( '#slide a' )

for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {

    anchors[i].addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        locked = true;
    })
}
```

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/EVyE8/1235/

Hope that helps!